# Does TensorFlow perform poorly for simple networks?

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, tensorflow

I've been experimenting with simple basic (intro tutorial-level) neural networks in various frameworks, but am confused about the performance I'm seeing in [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org).

For example, the simple network from [Michael Nielsen's tutorial](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/index.html) (MNIST digit recognition using L2 stochastic gradient descent in a network with 30 hidden nodes) performs much worse (takes about 8x as long per epoch, with all the same parameters) than a slightly adapted (using vectorization by mini-batch as suggested in [one of the tutorial exercises](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html#problem_269962)) version of [Nielsen's basic NumPy code](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/network2.py).

Does TensorFlow, running on a single CPU, always perform this badly? Are there settings I should tweak to improve performance? Or does TensorFlow only really shine with much more complex networks or learning regimes, so that it is not expected to do well for such simple toy cases?

---

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, print_function, division, unicode_literals)

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import time


def weight_variable(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1))


def bias_variable(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape))


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("./data/", one_hot=True)

sess = tf.Session()

# Inputs and outputs
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

# Model parameters
W1 = weight_variable([784, 30])
b1 = bias_variable([30])
o1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1, name='o1')
W2 = weight_variable([30, 10])
b2 = bias_variable([10])
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(o1, W2) + b2, name='y')

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

loss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
loss += 0.1/1000 * (tf.nn.l2_loss(W1) + tf.nn.l2_loss(W2))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.15).minimize(loss)

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1)), tf.float32))


for ep in range(30):
    for mb in range(int(len(mnist.train.images)/40)):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(40)
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

Comment: How much time is taken by `next_batch`? That function does a lot more stuff than Michael Nielsen's version which uses simple Numpy slicing

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: Is there a way to disable that "lot more stuff" so that it does exactly what Michael Nielsen's version does, so I have a more direct comparison?

Comment: maybe you could plug in TensorFlow into Michael Nielsen's version?

Comment: IE, Michael Nielsen uses slicing to do something like next_batch = data[slice...], so you can just do that and not use the "mnist.train.next_batch" at all. Things in " tensorflow.examples" are there for learning purposes are are not made to be efficient. In one case I saw an example in that directory having a 200x slowdown compared to a more efficient version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would expect that hand coded specialized simple networks running on CPU would run faster than tensorflow ones. The reason is usually connected to the graph evaluation system that tensorflow uses.

The benefit of using tensorflow is when you have much more complex algorithms and you want to be able to test for the correctness first and then be able to easily port it to use more machines and more processing units.

For example one thing you can try is to run your code on a machine that has a GPU and see that without changing anything in your code you would get a speed up, maybe faster than the hand coded example you linked.
You can see that the hand written code would require considerable effort to be ported to GPU.

Comment: And presumably then as I had a more complex network (convolutional, more layers, many more nodes, etc.) or more fancy learning (e.g. dropouts), even with a single CPU, TensorFlow would start to outperform what I could do with basic NumPy, right?

Comment: definitely, plus the code is being exercised by many other developers so is also more reliable.

Comment: Case in point, I tried numpy OpenBLAS on Z840 yesterday, and it was 430 G ops/second for large matrix multiplication, meanwhile TensorFlow gave me 1.1 T ops/second